# Trying to implement Logistic Regression with stochastic gradient descent but gettin KEYError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I'am trying to implement logistic regression with sgd. My dataset is splited like `train_features.npy`, `train_labels.npy`, `test_features.npy`, `test_labels.npy`. My sgd function is here:

```
def stoch_grd_dcnt(train, batch_size, n0, n1, max_epoch, delta):
    # getting the total number of classes
    k = train['Category'].nunique()
    theta = np.zeros((train.shape[1], k-1))
    theta_list = []
    theta_list.append(theta)
    loss_list = []
    loss_list.append(loss(theta, train))
    for epoch in range(max_epoch):
        print(epoch+1, "Epochs started.")
        n = n0/(n1 + epoch)
        train = train.sample(frac=1, random_state = 102)
        # dividing the training set into batches
        num_batch = int(train.shape[0]/batch_size)
        batches = np.split(train, num_batch, axis = 0)
        # theta update using gradient descent
        for i in range(num_batch):
            theta = np.array(grad_desc(np.array(theta), n, batches[i], k))
        theta_list.append(theta)
        # computing and storing the loss function using new theta
        loss_list.append(loss(theta, train))
        if(loss_list[-1] > (1 - delta) * loss_list[-2] and 
           epoch > 2):
            print("Not much progress, terminate")
            break
        print(epoch+1, "Epochs completed.")
    return theta_list, loss_list`
```

But When I try to run parameters part after whole implementation I got KEYError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Category'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-a1c0f72fef45> in <module>
      1 # 1. Run the first stochastic gradient descent on the training example
----> 2 params = stoch_grd_dcnt(Train, 16, 0.1, 1, 1000, 0.00001)
      3 theta_list = params[0]
      4 loss_list = params[1]
      5 #>> Number of epochs = 5

<ipython-input-34-d48e44f19d71> in stoch_grd_dcnt(train, batch_size, n0, n1, max_epoch, delta)
      1 def stoch_grd_dcnt(train, batch_size, n0, n1, max_epoch, delta):
      2     # getting the total number of classes
----> 3     k = Train['Category'].nunique()
      4     theta = np.zeros((train.shape[1], k-1))
      5     theta_list = []

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Category'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].